# Ajax - responseText working but responseXML null

Tags: php, ajax, responsetext

I am trying my first AJAX and having a problem with my xml receiving function. 
I alert responseText and I can see the xml returned from my server, but when I try and get responseXML I get null and the error.

Here is the php function that builds my xml

```
  header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    echo("<results>");
    echo("<table><![CDATA[tablereererere]]></table>");
    //echo("<ratedTable>".$_POST['ratedTable']."</ratedTable>\n");
    //echo("<table>".$_POST['table']."</table>\n");
    //echo("<post_id>".$_POST['post_id']."</post_id>\n");
    //echo("<user_id>".$_POST['user_id']."</user_id>\n");
    //echo("<rating>".$_POST['rating']."</rating>\n");
    echo("</results>");
```

And here is my javascript function which is processing the returned xml

```
function ajaxReceiver(http_request) {

    //this function continues to run until a result is returned and then it creates the new div
    if(http_request.readyState == 4) {

      response_xml = http_request.responseXML;
      response_text =  http_request.responseText;

      alert(response_text);
      alert(response_xml.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].textContent);
      //document.getElementById('floatingNotification').innerHTML = response_text;
       // alert(http_request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].textContent);
      //ratedTable = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("table").value;
      //alert(ratedTable);
      //message = response.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].textContent;
      //alert(message);
     //alert(message);
//this response contains the xml document that was returned by the php function.You can get any values out of the xml document and 
//use javascript dom to manipulate the contents on the page


    }
}
```

Comment: Im sure that it is just some small stupid mistake but I've been looking at this script for hours and starting to go cross eyed

Comment: I've had it with ajax arrragggadfereferfe293847(*&(*&&^!!!!!

Comment: One more suggestion, didn't notice this earlier -- try `Content-Type: text/xml` instead of `application/xml`, if you haven't, and see if that does anything.

Comment: I think the problem was that I was getting error messages back with my xml so the xml was invalid, the way I debuged that was to alert the textResponse so I could see the xml I was getting back.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because, even though you're setting the content-type correctly, you need to have an `<xml` tag in the top of your response. Also, you aren't closing your last tag properly.  This should work:

```
echo("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
echo("<results>");
echo("<ratedTable>".$_POST['ratedTable']."</ratedTable>");
echo("<table>".$_POST['table']."</table>");
echo("<post_id>".$_POST['post_id']."</post_id>");
echo("<user_id>".$_POST['user_id']."</user_id>");
echo("<rating>".$_POST['rating']."</rating>");
echo("<message>$message</message>");
echo("</results>");
```

For more info on how to define your XML: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: I changed how the quotes were positioned.  Can you try again? If that doesn't work can you post the responseText?

Comment: Actually, how are you debugging this?  If you're using the line with the table you spelled textContent wrong.

Comment: to debug im using chrome developer tools and alerting the responseText and the textContent

Comment: Maybe try putting a breakpoint in your code as opposed to alerting it.  Your code all looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the parent node improperly (`</results>` not `<results/>`) and you should (after sanitizing it) wrap all the POSTDATA in `<![CDATA[...]]>` tags to be safe.  Make sure it's UTF8 encoded, too (see [`utf8_encode()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php))

**EDIT:** and what wajiw said about the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` tag at the beginning.

### Edit: Example CDATA Block Usage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<myNode>
    <myData><![CDATA[
        Now I just throw in my data, for fun and profit!
        This way I can use special, reserved characters like <, > and &!
    ]]></myData>
</myNode>
```

### Edit Yet Again:

Why not give `Content-Type: text/xml`, NOT `application/xml`, a go?

Comment: Can you explain what postdata is? Is that  this part <?xml version='1.0'?>

Comment: Ok made those changes, getting the same result

Comment: Can you please post the output XML?  Also, you are still not using `CDATA` blocks, and that might be important depending on the content of those variables.  POSTDATA is the Data sent via POST (i.e., the contents of `$_POST`); sanitizing it, such as using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`, prevents invalid characters as well as some types of XSS attack vectors.

Comment: ok i see the point of the cdata, that would come in handy if I had unusual characters, but the thing is im getting back nice clean xml and it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to put the asynchronous property in the function "open()" to false.
Like this:

```
ajaxObject.open("POST", "my_XML_Generator.php", false);
ajaxObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
ajaxObject.send();
```

Comment: No it's not. Synchronous requests are always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't solve it until I put my results into subnodes, e.g.

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n");
echo("<summary>$summary</summary>\n");
echo("<content>$content</content>\n");
```

didn't work for me for some weird reason, but this does:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n");
echo("<page>\n");
echo("    <summary>$summary</summary>\n");
echo("    <content>$content</content>\n");
echo("</page>\n");
```

My code retrieving the answer is

```
function retrieveRequest(title)
{
    if (_xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && _xmlRequest.status == 200)
    {
        var xmlResponse = _xmlRequest.responseXML;
        _divSummary.innerHTML = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].textContent;
        _divContent.innerHTML = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].textContent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error happen to our team once and it took me a long time before we realized that the problem was in our XML data returned from the server. In particular, PHP script that generated return XML string was the culprit.

My solution was to *remove any white space from the beginning of the PHP script*. I mean any spaces, new lines, and/or tabs need to be removed from the beginning of the script, so that the first thing in the script is the `<?php` tag itself. It turned out that the `<?PHP` tag was not the first thing on the first line of my PHP script; somehow I started my code on the second line and the first script line was simply an empty one.

It drove me mad and it took some time for me to figure this out, so I hope someone else can benefit from this solution. It is very simple and easy to try if all else fails.